# Conditional statement in R dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have dataframe df as below.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(X = c(1, 2, 5, 7, 8), Y = c(3, 5, 8, 7, 2), Z = c(2, 
8, 7, 4, 3), R = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 66)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z", 
"R"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
df
class(df)
```

I have to modify df under two conditions.
First:
modify df so that  it check minimum between X,Y,Z  for each row and whichever is minimum get replaced with corresponding value of R.
Second case:
which is minimum between X,Y,Z,R in each row, it get replaced with maximum between X,Y,Z,and R and create a new df.
 How should i get that?
I tried ifelse and if and else but could not get what i want..
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new dataset "df1" with first three coumns of "df".  Multiply "df1" with "-1" so that maximum values become "min" (assuming that there are no negative values).  Here, in the example, the values were all unique per row.  So, you can use the function `max.col` and specify the `ties.method='first'`.  It will get you the index of maximum value (here it will be minimum) per row, `cbind` it will the `1:nrow(df)` to create the "row/column" index and extract the elements of "df1" based on that index (`df1[cbind..]`) and change those values to "R" column values (`<- df$R`). You could then change the original "df" columns ("df[1:3]") to new values.  If there are more than one "minimum" value per row, you could use the "loop" method described for the second case.

```
 df1 <- df[1:3]
 df1[cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(-1*df1, 'first'))] <- df$R
 df[1:3] <- df1
 df
 #  X  Y Z  R
 #1 6  3 2  6
 #2 6  5 8  6
 #3 6  8 7  6
 #4 7  7 6  6
 #5 8 66 3 66
```

Create a copy of "df" (`df2`), get the `max` values per row using `pmax`, loop over the rows of "df2" (`sapply(seq_len...)`) and change the "minimum" values in each row to corresponding "max" values ("MaxV"), transpose (`t`) and assign it back to the "df2" (`df2[]`)

```
 df2 <- df
 #only use this if there is only a single "minimum" value per row
 # and no negative values in the data 
 #df2[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(-1*df2, 'first'))] <- 
  #                                    do.call(pmax, df2)


  MaxV <- do.call(pmax, df2)
  df2 [] <-  t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(i) {
                x <- unlist(df2[i,])
                ifelse(x==min(x), MaxV[i], x)}))

  df2
  #  X  Y  Z  R
  #1 6  3  6  6
  #2 6  8  8  6
  #3 8  8  7  8
  #4 7  7  7  7
  #5 8 66 66 66
```

Comment: hi akrun, i am new in R, can you explain how second line of your code works ?

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what it did in second line of your code ? Thank you